# minZoom max Zoom google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming

im facing a problem when i set the maximum Zoom on the map it is fine than add minZoom than the map is not loaded. thank you

```
var mO = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.041213, -30.325532),
    zoom: 3,
    maxZoom:11,

    panControl:false,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    scaleControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    overviewMapControl:false,
    rotateControl:false,  
    zoomControl:true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that blank line was where you had the minZoom... maybe put minZoom before maxZoom?  Also, it's hard to tell from the code you posted, but is zoomControl the last line of your mapOptions object?  If so, you shouldn't have a comma at the end of the line.  You really should post a more complete code snippet of the working AND non-working versions of your code.  Copy/pasted, not re-typed, so that any typos will be shown.  At the very least, post up through the closing bracket for your mapOptions object.

Comment: here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429722/change-icon-on-google-maps

Comment: so when i add minZoom before max the map is loaded but it stays blank, only blue background